# Yii framework url with % symbol gives 400 status

Tags: php, url, yii

I have a search form which contains only one text field with submit button.

If user searches with any text then we send results to the browser based on the search string.

If the search string contains % symbol then I got bad request status (400),

How do I resolve this issue?

Note : I have used path type URL which is provided by Yii framework

Comment: The request was bad. Fix it. See the error log of your server, which normally tells you more specifically which part of the request triggered the error. Also your question contains too little information to say more. You create a wrong URL however the code that is related to that action is missing. And [phrases to avoid](http://stuck.include-once.org/#help4) include "Sir", "Thanks in advance", "ASAP" and even a bland "Help me" deimpresses people.

Comment: @hakra this is the best question on stackoverflow flow i have ever found the problem is only in the formatting and way of asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest you yo use `encodeURI`

```
 var value=$("#searchbar").val();
 var senddata=encodeURI("main.php?value="+value);

$.get(senddata,function(){

//write some code
})
```

Comment: I know this way of encoding, but this error happening because of server throws errors due to % symbol in url which is considered as invalid url, so I have used parameter type url instead of path type urls as u suggested

Comment: @Kanagu yes you are right `%` shows the error so you need to encode this  to `%25`